# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <Relation Class>could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the exception while updating the Parent entity with a new Child entity,

Here is my Sample Table

```
public class NavigationNode implements Serializable,Auditable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "NodeID")
private Long id;

@Embedded
private AuditSection auditSection = new AuditSection();

@Column(name = "Code", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String navCode;

@Column(name = "NodeTitle")
private String title;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "node2linkRel", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NavigationNodeID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LinkID") })
private Collection<Link> links;

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST} )
@JoinTable(name = "node2nodeRel", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ChildID") })
private Collection<NavigationNode> children;

@Column(name = "Visible")
private Boolean visible;
```

}

There is another Table called Link

```
public class Link implements Serializable,Auditable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "LinkID")
private Long id;

@Embedded
private AuditSection auditSection = new AuditSection();

@Column(name = "LinkUrl")
private String url;

@Column(name = "linkName")
private String linkName;

@Column(name = "VisibleInMenu")
private Boolean visibleInMenu;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "node2linkRel", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LinkID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NavigationNodeID") })
private NavigationNode node;
```

}

While Saving without the Links I am getting the above error.

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Navigation.links
>   could not initialize proxy

My requirements are

- I can created a Navigaiton with optional children and links, Update an Child/parent with optional children and links.
- If I delete Navigation Node then the related children should be deleted but I want to keep only the Link and delete the relation between Navigation and Link.
- If I try to delete the LInk record, only the relation between Navigation and link should be deleted.

How Can I achieve that and is this the correct Table configuration.

Also While deleting the Link or Node I am getting another exception.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: @ali4j I found the issue, It is because the for the Relational Collection attributes I am assigning a new object so it is not allowing to assign a new object while the Object is already persist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because I was trying to Assign a new Object List to the Links in navigation Table after getting the Object from the DataBase.

I was trying to break a Relation between a Link and Navigation. 
For achieving this I just remove the Link from the Links list in the Navigaition Table and save, so that the Relation between those entity breaks.

My requirement is not to delete the Link if I try to unlink the relation between Navigation and Link.